# faoutlier analysis takes too long

Tags: r, outliers

I'm doing an outlier analysis using `forward.search` in the `faoutlier` package in `R`, but it takes too long without any result. I just wanted to check whether I am doing it right, and how could I make the process done faster (e.g. by setting parameters). Here's the script:

```
library(faoutlier)

mydata.girls=read.table('data-girls.txt')

model.mydata.girls <-
'F1 =~ V1+V3+V5+V14+V19+V24+V28+V29+V31+V38+V40+V42+V44+V46+V48+V54+V63+V64+V65+V66+V69+V80
 F2 =~ V6+V9+V13+V17+V36+V37+V45+V49+V53+V56+V57+V60+V62+V67+V68+V71+V74+V75
 F3 =~ V4+V7+V11+V18+V25+V30+V32+V33+V35+V39+V43+V47+V50+V52+V77+V78+V79
 F4 =~ V10+V20+V23+V26+V34+V41+V58+V59+V70+V72+V73+V76
 F5 =~ V8+V22+V51'

FS<-forward.search(mydata.girls,model.mydata.girls)
```

Comment: Your model appears to have near-infinite combinatoric possibilities. How about you try a simple version where maybe `F1,...F5` each depend on no more than two variables and see what happens.  Also, have you verified that the model you built manually here conforms to the structure of a `sem::specifyModel` output?

Comment: You're probably right. I tried `robustMD` method after this and it said that IQR for at least one of your columns is zero. I found that much of my participants responded zero to questions V12 and V16. I removed them from the analysis and at least robustMD works.

Answer (score 1):

Some better optimizations were added to version 0.4 on CRAN now, which organize larger datasets more optimally and support estimating all models using parallel architecture via the `parallel` package. You can use a `setCluster()` to use all available cores during estimation, which I've found will dramatically reduce the estimation times for larger datasets. Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually, after I posted the question, I've found that there's a problem in my code that makes it run for too long time. Nevertheless, there were other times that I run codes that I wanted them to be speed up by means of using other CPU cores. This will be of very help to those situations for me. Thanks a lot.